# Custom view with 9patch bitmap as background

Tags: android, android-view

I want to create a custom view which has a 9-patch bitmap as background and can display two rows of text in the center of the view.
I have read the [official guide](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) on creating custom views but still don't know how to start.
I was able to draw the background in the `onDraw()` method using `canvas.drawBitmap(..)` 
This, works, but how can i draw a 9-patch bitmap and set the width and height? (the image size should be like `match_parent`.

To summarize i want to create a view like this:

```
+------------------+
|                  |
|  first row text  |
|  second row text |
|                  |
+------------------+
```

The box should have a 9-patch bitmap background and should have a width that matches the parent layout.
how can I implement this?

kind regards

Answer (score 1):

I think just regular TextView can cover your requirements. Try this,

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minLines="2"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="This is the first row \n This is the second row"/>
```

If you have any special reason to use CustomView, then don't need to build it from scratch, try to extend it from a proper one. (In your case TextView looks proper)